# 1 word per line from jinja2 template to HTML format

Tags: html, jinja2

I have a jinja2 template - test.html.j2 with variable {{ test }} contain string "this is a test". when it copy over to target node by using ansible template module it display entire string. May I know how to split the word like format below.

this
is
a
test

It works when is in .txt format but not .html

Playbook

```
- name: Test HTML
  hosts: all
  vars:
    - test: "This is a test"
  tasks:

  - name: Copy test.html
    template:
      src: test.html.j2
      dest: /tmp/{{ ansible_date_time.iso8601_basic }}.html
```

jinja2 template

Output Test
{{ test }}

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you need to apply "**replace**" filter (http://jinja.pocoo.org/docs/2.10/templates/#replace) in your html template file. Like this:

test.html.j2 :

```
{{ test | replace(' ', '<br/>') }}
```

In this template every space character should be replaced with HTML line break tag ("<br/>")

Answer (score 0):

Can you try as below? The | character is a literal block operator.

```
test: |
  this
  is
  a
  test
```